# Genus of union of elliptic curve and projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

Let $E\subset \mathbb P^2$ be a smooth irreducible complex cubic curve and $L\subset \mathbb P^2$ a complex projective line in general position. Let $C:=E\cup L$ be their union.
The assumption that $L$ is of general position means that there are three intersection points, each of multiplicity one, and they are all nodes, i.e. $C$ is a nodal curve. Is $C$ a stable curve?

To check stability, one considers the normalisation $\widetilde C \to C$. The normalisation map is bijective on smooth points, whereas nodes have two preimages. The smooth curve $\widetilde C$ consists of three components, each of them containing two preimages of the nodes. Then $C$ is stable iff all components of $\widetilde C$ are stable. An irreducible smooth curve is stable iff it has genus at least 2, or genus 1 with at least one marked point, or genus 0 with three marked points. (In our case, the marked points are just preimages of nodes.)

My question is: what are the genera of irreducible components of $\widetilde C$? It is clear that they should all have the same genera, and my intuition tells me that they should all have genus one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normalization induces a bijection of irreducible components, which means your conclusion that "$\widetilde{C}$ has three components" is incorrect. $\widetilde{C}$ has two components, in fact, and it's just the disjoint union of the cubic and the line. The relevant marked points are just the preimages of the nodes, so we have a disjoint union of a curve of genus one and a curve of genus zero, both with three marked points, and thus our curve is stable.

Comment: It was the (real) visual picture that led me astray, thanks for pointing out the mistake!